# how to highlight row on mouse click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with rows of data. I am able to highlight the table when the checkbox is checked. I would like to enable the highlight and enable the checkbox on a mouse click over the table. the problem with my code now is that when I click on the check box its triggers the event for the mouse click to as the check box is part of the `<tr>` how can I fix this.

```js
$('.form-check-input').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("rowColor");
  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("rowColor");
  }
});
$('#table1 tbody tr').on('click', function() {
  //$(this).find(".form-check-input").checked = true;
  var checkBox = $(this).find(".form-check-input");
  if (checkBox.is(':checked')) {
    checkBox.attr("checked", false);
    $(this).removeClass("rowColor");
  } else {
    checkBox.attr("checked", true);
    $(this).addClass("rowColor");
  }
});
```

```css
.rowColor {
  background-color: #dfecf6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" class="table table-striped">
  //thead
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td></td>
      <td class="checkboxtd"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue with above code is when checkbox clicked it also trigger parent element click event. you can stop that by calling `stopPropagation()` for event. here is updated code

```js
$('.form-check-input').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("rowColor");
  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("rowColor");
  }
});
$('#table1 tbody tr').on('click', function() {
  $('.form-check-input').trigger("click"); 
  return;
});
```

```css
.rowColor {
  background-color: #dfecf6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" class="table table-striped">
  //thead
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td>test</td>
      <td class="checkboxtd"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had two events overlap each other because the `checkbox` click was bubbling to the `tr` click. I added `e.stopPropagation();` to keep it from happening.

```js
$('.form-check-input').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("rowColor");
  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("rowColor");
  }
});
$('#table1 tbody tr').on('click', function() {
  //$(this).find(".form-check-input").checked = true;
  var checkBox = $(this).find(".form-check-input");
  if (checkBox.is(':checked')) {
    checkBox.attr("checked", false);
    $(this).removeClass("rowColor");
  } else {
    checkBox.attr("checked", true);
    $(this).addClass("rowColor");
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%
}
.rowColor {
  background-color: #dfecf6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" class="table table-striped">
  //thead
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp</td>
      <td class="checkboxtd">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="">
       </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all some other this about your code:

- you should use `checkBox.prop("checked", false);` and not `.attr` to set the current state of the checkbox.
- you normally want to listen to the `change` (or `input`) event on an input element if you want to get notified about a change a `click`. A checkbox could also be checked/unchecked by using other input devices like a keyboard.

To your problem, there are different ways of targeting the problem.

My first and highly suggested solution would be to rewrite the logic of your code: I would go with only changing the checked state of the checkbox in the `tr` event handler and then trigger the `change` event on the checkbox.

```js
$('.form-check-input').on('change', function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("rowColor");
  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("rowColor");
  }
});

$('#table1 tbody tr').on('click', function(e) {
  var checkBox = $(this).find(".form-check-input");
  if (!$(e.target).is(checkBox)) {
    // toggle the check state
    checkBox.prop("checked", !checkBox.is(':checked'));
    // trigger the change event
    checkBox.trigger("change")
  }
});
```

```css
.rowColor {
  background-color: #dfecf6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" class="table table-striped">
  //thead
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td></td>
      <td class="checkboxtd"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

If you really want to keep your code that way - which I won't suggest due to the above-mentioned reason - you could go with the way to prevent the propagation of the event in the `click` event handler of the `input` element, that way it won't reach the `tr` element.

```js
$('.form-check-input').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("rowColor");
  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("rowColor");
  }
});

$('#table1 tbody tr').on('click', function(e) {
  //$(this).find(".form-check-input").checked = true;
  var checkBox = $(this).find(".form-check-input");

  if (checkBox.is(':checked')) {
    checkBox.prop("checked", false);
    $(this).removeClass("rowColor");
  } else {
    checkBox.prop("checked", true);
    $(this).addClass("rowColor");
  }
});
```

```css
.rowColor {
  background-color: #dfecf6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" class="table table-striped">
  //thead
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td></td>
      <td class="checkboxtd"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

The other way would be to check in the event handler of the `tr` element if the `click` event originated from the `input` element, using `$(e.target).is(checkBox)`. That way you could also change your event listener to listen for `change` instead of `click` for the checkbox. But I wouldn't recommend that either.

```js
$('.form-check-input').on('change', function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("rowColor");
  } else {
    $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("rowColor");
  }
});

$('#table1 tbody tr').on('click', function(e) {
  //$(this).find(".form-check-input").checked = true;
  var checkBox = $(this).find(".form-check-input");
  if (!$(e.target).is(checkBox)) {
    if (checkBox.is(':checked')) {
      checkBox.prop("checked", false);
      $(this).removeClass("rowColor");
    } else {
      checkBox.prop("checked", true);
      $(this).addClass("rowColor");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.rowColor {
  background-color: #dfecf6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" class="table table-striped">
  //thead
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td></td>
      <td class="checkboxtd"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a few changes feel free to visit my solution in CodePen: https://codepen.io/juanmaescudero/pen/PojQKzm

Anyway I share you the code:

HTML:

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="">
      <td>highlight row</td>
      <td class="checkboxtd"><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 <table>
```

CSS:

```
.rowColor {
  background-color: #dfecf6;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".form-check-input").on("click", (e) => {
  e = e.target;
  if ($(e).is(":checked")) {
    $(e.closest("tr")).addClass("rowColor");
  } else {
    $(e.closest("tr")).removeClass("rowColor");
  }
});
```

Regards